# How to parse multi-line headers of SIP message using regex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, sip

I'm trying to extract `tag` from the `From:` header of a SIP messages.

My regex: `^(From:|f:)((?!\\n\\w).)*;[ ]*tag[ ]*=[ ]*([[:alnum:]]*)`

RFC 3261 allows multi-line headers. This new line should start with a whitespace. But i have a problem with multi-line headers. If the `tag` is on a new line, my regex is not working.

Example correct SIP Message:

```
INVITE sip:13@10.10.1.13 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.10.1.99:5060;branch=z9hG4bK343bf628;rport
Contact: <sip:15@10.10.1.99>
Call-ID: 326371826c80e17e6cf6c29861eb2933@10.10.1.99
CSeq: 102 INVITE
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX
Max-Forwards: 70
Date: Wed, 06 Dec 2009 14:12:45 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY
Supported: replaces
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 258
From: "Test 15" <sip:15@10.10.1.99>
 ; tag   =    fromtag
To: <sip:13@10.10.1.13>;tag=totag

v=0
o=root 1821 1821 IN IP4 10.10.1.99
s=session
c=IN IP4 10.10.1.99
t=0 0
m=audio 11424 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv
```

How can I properly parse the multi-line headers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use a proper parser or write one yourself?

Comment: @doron I have the proper parser built at BNF. But I want to extract some of the fields from the message to complete the parsing. Full parsing made too long.

Comment: "Full parsing made too long" - what does that mean?

Comment: https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/ <-- working on it

Comment: [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32236528/85371); Listed the livecoding vods for your hilarity. ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469)) /cc @doron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd second the motion to use/generate a proper parser.

There's nothing stopping you from parsing the headers in a separate step, but you can still specify the grammar declaratively, which is the main point.

The best part here is indeed

- the declarative style making it easier to extend with more grammar (the surrounding bits or more details like disallowing CTL characters)
- the "free" debugging tools (`#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG`, done)

Here's a simple take on the multiline header syntax :

- rfc 2616

  > Header fields can be extended over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at least one SP or HT
- rfc 822

  > ```
  >  field       =  field-name ":" [ field-body ] CRLF
  >
  >  field-name  =  1*<any CHAR, excluding CTLs, SPACE, and ":">
  >
  >  field-body  =  field-body-contents
  >                 [CRLF LWSP-char field-body]
  >
  >  field-body-contents =
  >                <the ASCII characters making up the field-body, as
  >                 defined in the following sections, and consisting
  >                 of combinations of atom, quoted-string, and
  >                 specials tokens, or else consisting of texts>
  > ```

So without further ado, here's a simple grammar for roughly that, parsing from any range of input iterators into a std::map:

```
using Headers = std::map<std::string, std::string>;
```

Here's the core of the parser:

```
    auto& crlf       = "\r\n";
    auto& tspecials = " \t><@,;:\\\"/][?=}{:";

    rule<It, std::string()> token, value;

    token = +~char_(tspecials); // FIXME? should filter CTLs
    value = *(char_ - (crlf >> &(~blank | eoi)));

    Headers headers;
    bool ok = phrase_parse(first, last, (token >> ':' >> value) % crlf >> omit[*lit(crlf)], blank, headers);

#ifdef DEBUG
    if (ok)          std::cerr << "DEBUG: Parse success\n";
    else             std::cerr << "DEBUG: Parse failed\n";
    if (first!=last) std::cerr << "DEBUG: Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(first,last) << "'\n";
#endif
```

You can see a live demo parsing the sample headers from your question:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a291f16fb8b0c8bc)</kbd>**

Printing:

```
Key: 'Allow', Value: 'INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY'
Key: 'CSeq', Value: '102 INVITE'
Key: 'Call-ID', Value: '326371826c80e17e6cf6c29861eb2933@10.10.1.99'
Key: 'Contact', Value: '<sip:15@10.10.1.99>'
Key: 'Content-Length', Value: '258'
Key: 'Content-Type', Value: 'application/sdp'
Key: 'Date', Value: 'Wed, 06 Dec 2009 14:12:45 GMT'
Key: 'From', Value: '"Test 15" <sip:15@10.10.1.99>
; tag   =    fromtag'
Key: 'Max-Forwards', Value: '70'
Key: 'Supported', Value: 'replaces'
Key: 'To', Value: '<sip:13@10.10.1.13>;tag=totag'
Key: 'User-Agent', Value: 'Asterisk PBX'
Key: 'Via', Value: 'SIP/2.0/UDP 10.10.1.99:5060;branch=z9hG4bK343bf628;rport'
```

Note that the `\r\n` combo is kept as-is in the value for the `From` header. If you want to normalize that to some other LWS character, such as a simple `' '`, use e.g.

```
value = *(omit[ crlf >> !(~blank | eoi) ] >> attr(' ') | (char_ - crlf));
```

Comment: Here's the vods of the live stream in case you like to see: [part #1](http://tinyurl.com/sip-ml-1), [part #2](http://tinyurl.com/sip-ml-2), [part #3](http://tinyurl.com/sip-ml-3) and [part #4](http://tinyurl.com/sip-ml-4). You can enjoy seeing me struggle with simple things and deployment issues, as well brainfarts and mental bugs.

Answer (score 2):

A line continuation character can be a space or a horizontal tab... depending on your regex parser you can match on \r\n[ /t] for line-continuation.  That said, your regex might be quite complex testing that wherever linear-whitespace could be found... you might be better off with a custom parser breaking the header lines and testing for what you need.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But why custom parser is easier to test than the regex?

Comment: It really just depends on your requirements for performance, items you're testing for, variations on input, if you plan to modify the headers, etc. etc.  You'll find a wide variety of SIP implementations with all sorts of oddities out there and you might not be able to regex your way out of some situations...

Comment: Probably yes. Most likely i will take your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the following pattern:

```
/(?i)(f(?:rom):(?:(?!^[^\r?\n]+)[\S\s])*((?:\s;\s*([^=]+)\s*=\s*([^\r?\n]+))))/g
```

Working demo at [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/yW3dN9/1)

Comment: Thanks for answer! I'm using Boost.Regex. Your pattern is unfortunately not working. =(

Comment: @Dolk13: Sorry, I am not familiar with the Boost regex engine, but as per my understanding Boost accepts PCRE :(.